# (LibGDX)DeltaTime Is Not Exact With Sprite Movement

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tile, 2d-games

I have a couple of sprites that follow a certain path in a TileMap and I base the sprite's movement off of DeltaTime. Since DeltaTime varies, it causes some of the sprites to overlap/past other sprites. Note that the sprite must go down one cell in the TileMap and in the opposite direction if it hits a certain tile. Here's the code for the sprite movement:

```html
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;


public class CentipedeBody1 extends Sprite {

    enum State{
        LEFT,RIGHT,DOWN
    }

    State currentState,previousState ;

    public static final float DOWN_MOVEMENT=7f;
    public float downMovCounter;
    public float speed;
    public float stateTime;
    TextureRegion image;
    Vector2 position,size;
    Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
    TextureRegion currentFrame;
    TextureRegion[]frames;
    Texture tilesImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("tile.png"));
    TextureRegion[][] splitTiles = TextureRegion.split(tilesImage, 8, 8);
    public CentipedeBody1(TextureRegion image, Vector2 position, Vector2 size) {
        super(new TextureRegion(image));
        setPosition(position.x,position.y);
        setSize(size.x,size.y);
        currentState=State.LEFT;
        previousState=State.LEFT;
        speed=8f;

   
    }

    public void update(TiledMap map) {

        float delta=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
 

        if(currentState ==State.LEFT){
          setPosition(getX()-speed*delta,getY());

            if(getX()<0) {
                previousState=currentState;
                currentState = State.DOWN;
                setFlip(true,false);
            }
        }

        if(currentState ==State.RIGHT){
            setPosition(getX()+speed*delta,getY());
            if(getX()> 19) {
                previousState=currentState;
                currentState = State.DOWN;
                setFlip(false,false);

            }
        }

        if(currentState ==State.DOWN){
            setPosition(getX(),getY()-1);
        
           
                downMovCounter=0;
                currentState =previousState==State.LEFT?
              State.RIGHT:State.LEFT;
           

        }



        TiledMapTileLayer cur = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(2);
        TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = new TiledMapTileLayer.Cell();


        if(cur.getCell(Math.round(getX()),Math.round(getY())).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("mushroom"))
        {


            if(getCurrentState()==State.LEFT)
            {
                setFlip(true,false);

            }
            else if(getCurrentState()==State.RIGHT)
            {
                setFlip(false,false);
            }

            previousState=currentState;
            currentState = State.DOWN;



        }
            }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If I spawn one Sprite one tile in front of the other Sprite they should move the same speed but one Sprite is usually faster/lower then the other. How would I make them always go the same speed with delta time

Comment: This probably isn't the cause of the delta time since delta time doesn't change mid-frame. Delta time only changes before each frame.

Comment: I updated my code so maybe you could help me find the problem. In my main class, i make two sprites(CentipedeBody1) in which one is one cell ahead of the other. I also call both of their update() methods

Comment: I can't see what would be wrong. Have you tried debugging your problem using standard `println` calls? Try printing your delta variables to see if they are the same. Also, if you're in eclipse, you can use `CTRL + SHIFT + F` to format your code to make it easier to read. Just a tip :)

Comment: Very interesting, both have the same delta time. They start to overlap when they go down a cell. Any ideas?

Comment: When they're going down you're doing `getY() - 1` instead if the usual `speed * delta` try changing that.

Comment: But I'm using a TileMap and I need it to go down exactly one cell. What should I do?